# displaying double variable problem (Arduino)

Tags: arduino, double, calculator, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

so I have a problem with displaying a double variable in OLED & IR remote calculator, like this (using u8g2):

```
displayTextOnRight(String(100000, 0)); //ex. of an void and a number
```

It displays: " "
But when I set to ex. 99999 it displays: "99999"

The same is with

```
displayTextOnRight(String(1000.00, 2));
```

It also displays nothing. (100.00 displays 100.00)

I tried values below zero and it crashes. When I try 6 it's empty whatever I type on my remote.

Please help.

Comment: 100000 is not a double (try 100000.0 ) To transform a (long) int to a string, use the proper syntax, e.g. `String(100000)`

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong. This would not work neither as you obviously expect

```
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 Serial.print("Test: ");Serial.println(String(99999,0));
}
```

The function `String` handles integers differently than floats:

- for floats you specify the number of decimal digits ( 2 as default )
- for int you specify the radix ( DEC as default )